# Not able to perform update and delete operation using custom html input fields

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner to Django. I am now doing a small project and I am encounter an issue while doing the update and delete operation. I am using forms.py but using custom input fields in html file. I have tried many ways but it returns errors. When I try to update it creates a new entry instead of update. When I perform delete nothing happens. Please go through the below code and help me out to resolve this.

**urls.py**

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    
    urlpatterns = [
       path('', views.home, name='home'),
       path('contacts', views.contacts, name='contacts'),
       path('update/', views.update, name='update'),
       path('delete/', views.delete, name='delete'),
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
    

    def update(request, contact_id):
       details = Contact.objects.filter(id=contact_id)
       if request.method == 'POST':
           form = ContactForm(request.POST or None, instance=details)
           if form.is_valid():
               form.save()
               return redirect('contacts')
       else:
           return render(request, 'update.html', {'details':details})
    
    def delete(request, contact_id):
       contact = Contact.objects.all()
       if request.method == 'POST':
           details = Contact.objects.get(id=contact_id)
           details.delete()
           return redirect('contacts')
       return render(request, 'contacts.html', {'contact':contact})
```

**contacts.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Home ></a>
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">#</th>
                      <th scope="col">First</th>
                      <th scope="col">Last</th>
                      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                      <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  {% for item in contact  %}
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">{{item.id}}</th>
                      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.email}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.mobile}}</td>
                      <td><a href="{% url 'update' item.id %}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                          <a href="{% url 'delete' item.id %}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  {% endfor %}  
                  </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**update.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5 mt-5">
                <a href="{% url 'contacts' %}" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Contacts ></a>
                <form action=" url '{{details.id}}' " method="post" autocomplete="off">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for item in details %}
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="full name" name="name" value="{{item.name}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@name.com" name="email" value="{{item.email}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="mobile" class="form-label">Mobile</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Eg: 0546321023" name="mobile" value="{{item.mobile}}">
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Update</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**forms.py**

```
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from .models import Contact
    
    class ContactForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Contact
            fields = ['name','email','mobile']
```

**models.py**

```
    from django.db import models
    
    # Create your models here.
    class Contact(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
        mobile = models.IntegerField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

Comment: `action=" url '{{details.id}}' "`?

Comment: You haven't defined `contact_id` in both the urls i.e. `delete` and `update` in `path` function.

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py make these changes:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.home, name='home'),
   path('contacts', views.contacts, name='contacts'),
   path('update/<str:contact_id>/', views.update, name='update'),
   path('delete/<str:contact_id>/', views.delete, name='delete'),
]
```

Your update and delete views work fine but they were not getting any contact_id before.
Now by making these changes, let's say https://localhost:8000/update/1 is requested then urldispatcher will match the URLs and call the view functions as

```
update(request,contact_id='1')
delete(request,contact_id='1')
```

Try reading this section of django docs : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views